# SQL - Join 2 queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two querys:

```
Select trunc(create_dtime) as Day, Count(Player_Id) as New_Users
From Player
Where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group By Trunc(Create_Dtime)
```

and

```
Select trunc(create_dtime) as Day,Count(Player_Id) as Retained_Users
From Player
Where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
And Trunc(Init_Dtime)  >= Trunc(Sysdate) - 7
Group By Trunc(Create_Dtime)
Order By Day Asc
```

Every day has a value, and I want to join these two queries together so I only have one query instead of two.

Comment: What query have you attempted in order to get your desired result-set?

Comment: What's the tables' structure ?

Comment: To answer your question, you should show us what your want then there are days in query one that don't occur in query two, and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry about that, the question/answer wasn't very clear. I think I took care of it. Can you please upvote again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a join there:

```
SELECT
  TRUNC(CREATE_DTIME) AS DAY,
  COUNT(PLAYER_ID) AS NEW_USERS,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN TRUNC(INIT_DTIME) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7 THEN PLAYER_ID ELSE NULL END)     AS RETAINED_USERS
FROM PLAYER
WHERE TRUNC(CREATE_DTIME) >= TO_DATE('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATE_DTIME)
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an inner join, unless you want to include results that do not have a match in the other query.  Otherwise you just use:

```
SELECT * FROM query1 INNER JOIN query2 ON query1.Day=query2.Day
```

I should note this is the syntax for MySQL I didn't realize you tagged it as Oracle.  The syntax is probably going to be similar if not identical, but I have never used Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I was just forgetting to label the columns.

```
Select one.Day, one.New_Users, two.Retained_Users
From
(
Select trunc(create_dtime) as Day, Count(Player_Id) as New_Users
From Player
Where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group By Trunc(Create_Dtime)
) One
Inner Join 
(
Select trunc(create_dtime) as Day,Count(Player_Id) as Retained_Users
From Player
Where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
And Trunc(Init_Dtime)  >= Trunc(Sysdate) - 7
Group By Trunc(Create_Dtime)
Order By Day Asc
) Two On One.Day=Two.Day
Order By 1
```